# Can a node of a linked list have pointers to multiple nodes?

Tags: linked-list

I'm new to programming so forgive me if I'm vague. I'm trying to code a ticket reservation system as part of a school project where the seats in the auditorium are separate nodes as part of a linked list. Each seat must point to the other seats surrounding it. For example, the middle seats will have 4 pointers, the edge seats will have 2 or 3 pointers depending on where it is (corner seat or a seat in the first or last row). From what I've read and learned a linked list is linear and can only point to the next node in the list. Is there anyway for a node in a linked list have pointers pointing to multiple nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Linked list is based on your implementation. It can have multiple links to other nodes. Common usages of link lists have single links and double links, but there is no stopping how many links you have. In fact, a tree implemented using links would ideally have more than one link from each node. .

In your case, what you need is a graph made of links, rather than a list. I suggest you read up about the implementation of a graph in c++ using links. That will help you get a clearer idea about how to go about solving your problem.

Here is a slightly elaborate explaination of the graph data structure and how you can implement it in c++. https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/graph-implementation-cpp/

Also, welcome to the wonderful world of programming.